# how to create and use session scope variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In java, jsf it would be something like `private string x ["SessionScope"]` or something like that.
But how to do this in rails?
I need to create a session scoped variable in one view to use it in another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First look in the documentation about the [Session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session)

There is variable, a hash that keeps session data. It can be used inside controller, view, etc.

For example.

## Controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def first
    session[:var] = "data"
  end

  def second
    puts session[:no_var]
    puts session[:var]
  end

end
```

If you first visit action `first`, it will set the `session` has with key `:var` to `"data"`, and later when you visit `second` action it will print

```
nil
data
```

If in other session you first visit `second` action it will print.

```
nil
nil
```